# How do i pass an Entity from selected row in rowtemplate to AbstractEntityListProvider

Tags: codenameone

I have fetched data and populated in view using provider and `rowTemplate`.

Upon clicking the row, I want to pass the entity to another provider which will trigger `getRequest` with the values of the entity.

*How do I go about passing this selected entity to the provider?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding a lead component button to your row, and bind it to an action, so that it triggers an action which will be caught by your controller.  Your controller will contain the logic that does something with this event, such as passing the entity to a provider.

I've created a github repo with a small example of this here:
https://github.com/shannah/coderad-entitylist-sample

The key parts.  The view:

```
<define-category name="ROW_CLICKED" />
...
<entityList layout-constraint="center"
                provider="com.example.myapp.providers.SampleListProvider.class"

    >
        <row-template>
            <y rad-leadComponent="ClickMeButton">
                <radLabel tag="UserProfile.name"/>
                <button uiid="ClickMeButton" hidden="true">
                        <bind-action category="ROW_CLICKED"/>
                </button>
            </y>

        </row-template>
    </entityList>
```

Notice the `define-category` tag, which defines a ROW_CLICKED action category, which we will use in our button.

Next, inside the `<row-template>` we wrap the row in a container.  I use a `<y>` container, but you can use any type.  The key is the `rad-leadComponent="ClickMeButton"` which will pipe all events for the container to the child component with uiid "ClickMeButton", which will be our button.

Then the Button has a bind-action with our ROW_CLICKED category, so that it will fire events up to our controller.

In the controller:

```
protected void initControllerActions() {
        super.initControllerActions();
        addAction(StartPage.ROW_CLICKED, evt-> {
            evt.consume();
            UserProfile profile = (UserProfile)evt.getEntity();
            Dialog.show("Hello", "You clicked " + profile.getName(), "OK", null);
        });
    }
```

So you can see that we can get the entity from the event.  Here I just show a dialog with some entity details, but you could alternatively pass the entity to another provider.

Comment: @steve-hannah.Thanks though my main issue really is in my AbstractListProvider am not able to get the entity passed. The example passes the Entity to the Controller. I would like to have the entity passed to provider and from there I can do logic on the getEntities(...) method based on the values of the Entity.

Comment: You need to go through the controller to handle the event in the UI.  From there you can do what you like with the entity, including to send it to your provider.  E.g. Your provider could be set up to just return the results of a list of entities.  So you would update that list, and send a refresh request (i.e. call theEntityListView.refresh()) to any views using your provider.